# Can I have R vignette with a pre-compiled PDF with manual index.html show up the vignette list?

Tags: r, r-mosaic

I want to include a pre-compiled PDF as a vignette in a R package. The PDF is not generated via Sweave. Without a .Rnw to process, there is no `\VignetteIndexEntry` to cause the usual automatic generation of index.html and `Meta/vignette.rds`.

I created an index.html in `inst/doc` that is copied into `doc` during installation. This is corrected linked from the main package help page. However, when I load the package and execute `browseVignettes("MyPackage")`, I get

```
No vignettes found by browseVignettes("MyPackage")
```

This makes sense, because R apparently has no way to know that the package has a vignette. The installed package has no `Meta/vignette.rds` file. Can I somehow get my PDF to appear with `browseVignettes()`?

### `pdfpages`

I'm familiar with the [approach taken by the mosaic package](https://github.com/rpruim/mosaic/blob/master/inst/doc/MinimalR.Rnw), which is to use `pdfpages` to include the entire PDF. While clever, I feel like there should be a better way that avoids the proliferation of files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a static (prebuilt) PDF vignette in R package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716498/using-a-static-prebuilt-pdf-vignette-in-r-package)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right after Yihui....

Make a fake Rnw that looks like this:

```
%\VignetteIndexEntry{User manual}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

And put it in `inst/doc` along side your precompiled vignette and you will be all set.

Comment: Does this obviate the need for a Makefile?

Comment: This approach seems to work perfectly. I thought that R might clobber the pre-existing PDF when it processed the Rnw, but it didn't.

Comment: I don't use a Makefile, something I need to learn I suppose.  You just drop that text in, and separately prepare your vignette.  When you run 'R CMD CHECK...` it works.  I can't remember where I found this trick, it's not in SO.  But it's not original to me.

Comment: I came across this trick on [Rd] while trying to find solutions to this exact question today.
[Henrik Bengtsson](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2012-April/063846.html)

Comment: @Benjamin Excellent, good to give the proper credit.  Thanks for providing the link.

Comment: this does not work for me in R 3.3.2 where an R CMD check halts after a "system cannot find the file specified" error.

Comment: Double check everything.  I run checks on files like this almost daily.

Comment: yeah, still not working. I have both the fake file and the pdf in inst/doc and R CMD check says that the vignette source in inst/doc is missing from the vignettes directory. Does it matter what the VignetteBuilder: is in DESCRIPTION? I'm using knitr. Do I need a dummy knitr file instead of this dummy Sweave file?

Comment: It does matter as so some other settings; check out section 1.4.2 "Non-Sweave vignettes" in *Writing R Extensions*.  Sounds like something small is missing or wrong in your settings, you'll find it!

Comment: the only thing I see is that it says to include a makefile, which you say you don't use. Maybe I have the files in the wrong spots. I have the .pdf in both vignettes/ and inst/doc and the .Rnw file in just vignettes/, is that right?

Comment: You are running `BUILD` first, and running `CHECK` on the tarball, correct?  And if you temporarily take out all things related to the vignette, it builds and checks correctly?  If so, try adding one thing back at a time.  Maybe try putting in a trivial test vignette and see if that works (i.e., use the dummy file above but put Hello in it).  And are you using RStudio?  That might change things substantially.

Comment: I found another solution, but I think it could be helpful if you edited the answer to indicate exactly what file you put where.

Answer (score 2):

R definitely needs a better way to deal with vignettes: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.devel/31967 Before my proposal is approved and implemented, we still have to live with the dark voodoo of Makefile. For example, you can put a `fake.Rnw` and a `real.pdf` under `inst/doc`, and `mv real.pdf fake.pdf` in the Makefile. In `fake.Rnw`, you just follow the rule of `\VignetteIndexEntry{}`.

Comment: Just to be clear, does this mean you put a file named `Makefile` and containing the single line `mv real.pdf fake.pdf` in the top of your package source directory?

Answer (score 1):

The `mosaic` package now [apparently uses the `R.rsp` package](https://github.com/rpruim/mosaic/tree/dd62be476db5f5b46db63c265197a1133f4688ad/vignettes) which has an "asis" driver that allows including an existing file and creating the `VignetteIndexEntry`. This looks much less like a hack than using `pdfpages` or a dummy `.Rnw` file (which [doesn't seem to work anymore in R 3.1](https://www.marshut.net/ksrwmr/vignette-from-existing-pdf-manual.html)).

Example: For a file `V1MinimalR.pdf`, there is a corresponding `V1MinimalR.pdf.asis` file with the following contents:

```
%\VignetteIndexEntry{Minimal R for Intro Stats}
%\VignetteEngine{R.rsp::asis}
```

The `DESCRIPTION` contains (among others) the following:

```
Suggests: R.rsp
VignetteBuilder: knitr, R.rsp
```

This is also detailed in [this answer by Henrik Bengtsson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24111191/946850), the author of the [R.rsp package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.rsp/index.html).