# VignetteBuilder entry forcing "prebuild" of index when releasing R package to CRAN

Tags: r, indexing, package, cran, vignette

I am building a new R package. I have the same problem given  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30976308/how-do-i-prebuild-a-vignette-index-for-an-r-package). I have also gone through the links suggested. But I keep getting rejections because the note says

> "Package has a VignetteBuilder field but no prebuilt vignette index.
>   So please add a vignette index."

I went to the CRAN package list for  [latest packages](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_date.html) and then went through the code of packages like    [hyfo](https://github.com/Yuanchao-Xu/hyfo) , mldr   and few others which have all released in the past few days. None of them have an index file. But, my code below is getting rejected. My code does not show any warnings or errors or NOTES when I run `devtoold::check()`. I am not getting any warnings/errors on `devtools:build_win()` as well.
Any ideas on what I am missing?

I am using R version 3.2.2 on windows.  My `DESCRIPTION` file which has the following

```
Package: Mypackage
Suggests:
    knitr,
    rmarkdown,
    R.rsp
VignetteBuilder: knitr
RoxygenNote: 5.0.1
```

In the vignettes directory, the file `Mypackage.Rmd`  has

```
title: "Mypackage"
author: "blah"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  html_document:
    fig_width: 7
    fig_height: 6
    fig_caption: true
vignette: >
    %\VignetteIndexEntry{Mypackage}
    %\VignetteEngine{R.rsp::asis}
    %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---
## Introduction
The contents of the vignette
```

How do I create the vignette index or how do I make this NOTE disappear?

Comment: Maybe try `output: rmarkdown::html_vignette` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Ok 2 issues with this.

### Vignette Index

First you need to have a `build/vignette.rds` file listing the vignettes. You can check this with:

```r
> readRDS("build/vignette.rds")
                File            Title       PDF                          R           Depends         Keywords
1      Mypackage.Rmd        Mypackage       Mypackage.html     Mypackage.R  
2        MyGuide.Rmd        MyGuide         MyGuide.html         MyGuide.R
```

Here the "Title" column is the title from `\VignetteIndexEntry{Mypackage}` and the rest are names of the files.

Notice there 2 additional blank fields "Depends" and "Keywords" here. You can create a new data.frame if you don't have one already.

```r
file <- data.frame(matrix(NA, 1, 6))
colnames(file) <- c("File", "Title", "PDF", "R", "Depends", "Keywords")
file[1,] <- c("MyPackage.Rmd", "MyPackage", "MyPackage.html", "MyPackage.R", "", "")
saveRDS(file, file = "vignette.rds")
```

To add a row with a new vignette to an existing data.frame:

```r
file <- readRDS("build/vignette.rds")
file[3,] <- c("import_reactome.Rmd", "Importing pathways from databases", "import_reactome.html", "import_reactome.R", "", "")
saveRDS(file, file = "vignette.rds")
```

### Generating static HTML vignettes

These vignettes are not generated on CRAN and must be pre-generated before upload. Run `knitr::knit` in RStudio on an Rmd file is the easiest way to do this. Then copy the output file to `vignettes/MyPackage.html`. You can also skip building vignettes by copying it to `inst/doc/MyPackage.html`.

You can add this line to return an HTML file when building the package.

```
title: "Mypackage"
author: "blah"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  html_document:
    fig_width: 7
    fig_height: 6
    fig_caption: true
    keep_html: true       ### <- add this line
vignette: >
    %\VignetteIndexEntry{Mypackage}
    %\VignetteEngine{R.rsp::asis}
    %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---
```

You *do not* need a markdown file. You can add the following line to `.Rbuildignore` to prevent it being included.

```
^vignettes/plot_directed.md#
```

#### Passing checks with devtools

For more details see the [Static_PDF_and_HTML_vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.rsp/vignettes/R_packages-Static_PDF_and_HTML_vignettes.pdf) from `R.rsp`. This describes how to use the `R.rsp::asis` engine.

The key part is that you need to have both a `vignettes/MyPackage.html` and `vignettes/MyPackage.html.asis` file. The `vignettes/MyPackage.html.asis` file only needs 3 lines, the rest are optional.

```
%\VignetteIndexEntry{MyPackage}
%\VignetteEngine{R.rsp::asis}
%\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
```

Once these files are included the `devtools::install(build_vignettes = TRUE)` and `devtools::check()` should run as expected.