# Package has a VignetteBuilder field but no prebuilt vignette index

Tags: r, package, devtools, cran, vignette

I am submitting a package to CRAN and I have got the below warning from the reviewers team:

> Package has a VignetteBuilder field but no prebuilt vignette index.

that I have in fact seen also when running `devtools::release()`. I am using the last `R` version as `R version 3.3.1` and have the following `.Rmd` vignette source:

```
---
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: rmarkdown::html_vignette
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{<my vignette title>} 
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::knitr}
  %\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
---
```

Moreover, I have included `knitr` in the `DESCRIPTION` file as per default:

```
Suggests:
    knitr
VignetteBuilder:
    knitr
```

I have looked around and, although the issue seems to be quite common, I have not been able to understand why the index does not build (and how to force build it).

---

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30976308/how-do-i-prebuild-a-vignette-index-for-an-r-package) and links therein are the top google results but do not solve the problem.

Comment: Do you have no `title`? And the last line is sometimes `%VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}` or just `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Comment: The title is there (I just didn't include it in the question body) and so is the `%VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}`. I suppose the problem is elsewhere, it must be in the building properties or the like.

Comment: I have had the same answer. What was your solution ?

Comment: You might want to check your `.Rbuildignore`. For me the issue was that I had `build` included there, which you should not do.

Answer (score 3):

This requires a `build/vignettes.rds` or `Meta/vignettes.rds` file. This file is automatically generated by `devtools`. Please make sure that you **do not** delete it or list it in `.Rbuildignore` (check for a line containing `build` `Meta` or `^build/vignettes.rds$` `^Meta/vignettes.rds$` and delete it from the file).

Comment: devtools puts those ignores in there. Are you saying that we should remove every time what devtools puts into Rbuildignore?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error. I made the following changes to my package, which had been suggested before, but some in comments, and not with clear verification about what worked and what did not.

First, I made changes to the `vignette:` specification in the header so that it now reads as follows (note the difference in the encoding specification line, from `%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to `%\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}`, which matches the directions in https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/r-package-vignette.html which seem to have changed)

```
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{The import package}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
```

Without these changes I had problems where I would either get warnings locally or remotely, but this made things more consistent.

Second, and potentially most important, I removed `^build` from my `.Rbuildignore`, importantly, `devtools` did not add it back, so I wonder if this is some legacy behavior or if I potentially added it myself at some point. I did *not* remove `^Meta` (I tried but `devtools` added the ignore back).

These changes resolved the note consistently and the package is now released :-)