# How to resolve NOTE in `R CMD check` when include static PDF file in vignette?

Tags: r, pdf, vignette

I wish to include a static PDF file in vignette of my R package [`biglasso`](https://github.com/YaohuiZeng/biglasso). I followed the instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716498/using-a-static-prebuilt-pdf-vignette-in-r-package) and [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.rsp/vignettes/R_packages-Static_PDF_and_HTML_vignettes.pdf). However when I run `R CMD check`, there is always a NOTE saying:

```
Vignette sources in 'inst/doc' with no 'vignettes' directory: 
  'biglasso.pdf.asis' 
A 'vignettes' directory is required as from R 3.1.0
```

and

```
* checking for old-style vignette sources ... NOTE
Vignette sources only in 'inst/doc':
  'biglasso.pdf.asis'
A 'vignettes' directory is required as from R 3.1.0
and these will not be indexed nor checked
```

[Here](https://win-builder.r-project.org/G0T8oVl2B2E6/00check.log) is the complete package check information.

Could anyone explain to me what this note means and how to fix it?