# NOTE: "Found the following (possibly) invalid file URI", when linking to static pdf file in html vignette, R-CMD-CHECK, R package development

Tags: r, package

I am creating an R package. I want to include a static pdf file as a vignette which appears on the GitHub website. The GitHub website only takes html vignettes and articles, and therefore I have used the following code to create a html vignette, which links to the pre-existing static pdf file. The html vignette is called "Overview" and the pre-existing static file is called "overview_vignette.pdf".

```
---
title: "Overview"
output: rmarkdown::html_vignette
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{Overview}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---

Please click the link below to access the *Overview* vignette, which is a pdf document and therefore cannot be directly viewed through this html vignette.

<!--- <iframe src="overview_vignette.pdf"/> -->

[Vignette: Overview](overview_vignette.pdf){target="_blank"}
```

The code works fine, but when running R-CMD-CHECK using the win builder:

```
devtools::check_win_devel()
```

I get the following NOTE:

```
Found the following (possibly) invalid file URI:
  URI: overview_vignette.pdf
    From: inst/doc/Overview.html
```

I believe I must eliminate all NOTEs before submitting to CRAN (or at least eliminating them all will ease this process). I am successfully able to link the static pdf vignettes, the issue is eliminating this note.

The overview_vignette.pdf link is not invalid, and the file is successfully linked to on my GitHub website. All other examples of this error I have found online, the URL is actually invalid in some way, and the examples normally have links to URLs on the internet. I am unsure what the issue is here. Help would me much appreciated!

Also, maybe worth mentioning, I am not getting the same NOTE as in this post: [How to resolve NOTE in `R CMD check` when include static PDF file in vignette?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41255573/how-to-resolve-note-in-r-cmd-check-when-include-static-pdf-file-in-vignette)

Comment: I am getting a different NOTE than the one reported in the other stack question, which also doesn't have an answer. My issue is not with inserting the link to the static pdf, I can do that successfully. The issue is also not about relative filepaths on GitHub. The issue is the NOTE I get when running R-CMD-CHECK using the win builder, as described above. Many thanks.

Comment: Has your last comment been deleted? Many thanks for your help, but the issue is not with linking to the static pdf or with generating the vignette, it's about the NOTE when running R-CMD-CHECK.