# Using a static (prebuilt) PDF vignette in R package website throw pkgdown::build_site

Tags: r, pdf, devtools, pkgdown

I'm using the following code to generate **website** for the `R` package:

```
pkgdown::build_site(
    pkg          = "."
  , examples     = TRUE
  , document     = TRUE
  , run_dont_run = FALSE
  , seed         = 12345
  , lazy         = FALSE
  , override     = list()
  , preview      = NA
  , new_process = TRUE
  )
```

However, my R package contains a static (prebuilt) PDF vignette ([Using a static (prebuilt) PDF vignette in R package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19716498/707145)) and I want to include this static (prebuilt) PDF vignette.

**sessionInfo**

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/atlas/libblas.so.3.10.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/atlas/liblapack.so.3.10.3

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] pkgdown_1.3.0        PakPMICS2018hh_0.1.0 usethis_1.5.0       
[4] devtools_2.0.2.9000 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] clisymbols_1.2.0  xfun_0.7          remotes_2.0.4     purrr_0.3.2      
 [5] rematch2_2.0.1    rcmdcheck_1.3.3   testthat_2.1.1    htmltools_0.3.6  
 [9] rlang_0.3.4.9003  pkgbuild_1.0.3    R.oo_1.22.0       pillar_1.4.1     
[13] glue_1.3.1        withr_2.1.2       R.utils_2.8.0     xopen_1.0.0      
[17] sessioninfo_1.1.1 R.cache_0.13.0    stringr_1.4.0     commonmark_1.7   
[21] R.methodsS3_1.7.1 memoise_1.1.0     evaluate_0.14     knitr_1.23.2     
[25] callr_3.2.0       ps_1.3.0          curl_3.3          Rcpp_1.0.1       
[29] backports_1.1.4   desc_1.2.0        rversions_2.0.0   pkgload_1.0.2    
[33] fs_1.3.1          R.rsp_0.43.1      digest_0.6.19     stringi_1.4.3    
[37] processx_3.3.1    rprojroot_1.3-2   cli_1.1.0         tools_3.6.0      
[41] magrittr_1.5      tibble_2.1.2      crayon_1.3.4      whisker_0.3-2    
[45] pkgconfig_2.0.2   MASS_7.3-51.4     xml2_1.2.0.9000   prettyunits_1.0.2
[49] assertthat_0.2.1  rmarkdown_1.13    roxygen2_6.1.1    httr_1.4.0       
[53] rstudioapi_0.10   R6_2.4.0          compiler_3.6.0    git2r_0.25.2
```

Comment: You could try [this approach using a standard Sweave vignette ... including a prebuilt pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56512026/143305) and see if `pkgdown` lets you have it.  Passes all standard R build and check steps without added dependencies as Sweave is standard -- yet creates (_i.e._ wraps) the prebuilt pdf.

Comment: Thanks @DirkEddelbuettel for your useful comment. However, I'm not able to get the vignette in `pkgdown` created package website. Any thoughts, please.

Comment: According to [this issue](https://github.com/r-lib/pkgdown/issues/781), you can't do this right now.